# Given a query that returns [1, 1] [2, 3], [5,1], How to you use that result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activemodel

Given:

```
class ThreadParticipations
  scope :unread, lambda{ |user| where(:user_id => user.id, :read => false) }
end

ThreadParticipations
  .unread(current_user)
  .includes(:thread => :project)
  .group('projects.id')
  .count('threads.id')
```

Which outputs:

```
 => { 1 => 15, 3 => 10 }
```

How do I use that result to update my list. Given in the result set 1 & 3 are project_ids, how can I iterate through that results to update a list like:

```
# iterates over @projects
<div>
 <li>Project_id 1, unread count = 15</li>
 <li>Project_id 2, unread count = 0</li>
 <li>Project_id 3, unread count = 10</li>
 <li>Project_id 4, unread count = 0</li>
 <li>Project_id 5, unread count = 0</li>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: "update a list" - what does that mean? Update as in a database record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand, you just want to iterate on the hash to output the html?

```
<ul>
    <% { 1 => 15, 3 => 10 }.each_pair do |k,v| %>
        <li>Project_id <%= k %>, unread count = <%= v%></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

edit: like that?

```
<ul>
    <% [[1,1], [2, 3], [3, 15]].each do |project_id, unread_count| %>
        <li>Project_id <%= project_id %>, unread count = <%= unread_count %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not a hash it's an array like [1,1], [2,3], [5,4]

Comment: For the sake of people reading your code, please give your block variables more useful names than `k` and `v`. Alphabet soup should be food, not code.

Comment: I understand that `k,v` stand for "key" and "value", but I'm weird that way. I agree that for examples something mnemonic is better.

Comment: For me `k` and `v` are much easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

First off: Your HTML is invalid. `li` elements go inside `ul`'s or `ol`'s, not `div`'s. The code you're looking for is:

```
<ul>
  <% hash.each do |project_id, unread_count| %>
    <li>Project_id <%= project_id %>, unread count = <%= unread_count %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```